# phpmailer attatch post data pdf file without save

Tags: php, base64, phpmailer, jspdf, html2pdf

hello im trying to send mail with input form javascript jspdf via phpmailer

mail sent ok but file were broken if i get $_POST['data'] through original php file.
how i can deliver jspdf file with $_POST['data'] to phpmailer?

i tried many ways but it didn't help much.
thank you for reading this

**form_input.php**

```
  var create_pdf = document.getElementById("create_pdf");
  create_pdf.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    html2canvas($('#pdf_wrap')[0] ,{    
      //logging : true,     
      //proxy: "html2canvasproxy.php",
      allowTaint : true,    
      useCORS: true,        
      scale : 2         
    }).then(function(canvas) {  
      
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');           
        var doc = new jsPDF("p", "px");
        var options = {
             pagesplit: true
        };

        var imgWidth = 210; 
        var pageHeight = 295;  
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;

        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        var position = 0;

        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          doc.addPage();
          doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }


        //Send mail on other php   
        $.post("mail_send.php", 
        {
            data: doc.output('datauristring')
        }, function () {}).done(function() {/*SOME CODE*/});    
       // doc.save( 'file.pdf');

    });
  });
```

**mail_send.php**

```
require 'plugin/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'plugin/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';
require 'plugin/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(!empty($_POST['data']))
{
    echo $_POST['data'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.test.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'smtpid@dot.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                  // TCP port to connect to
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->setFrom('setmail@mail.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('user@mail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        // ----------Attachments this doesn't work. delivered broken pdf file.
        $base = explode('data:application/pdf;base64,', $_POST['data']);
        $mail->addStringAttachment($base, 'pdfName.pdf');
        // -----------
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';

        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your data, but I think is the problem

```
$base = explode('data:application/pdf;base64,', $_POST['data']);
$mail->addStringAttachment($base, 'pdfName.pdf');
```

This will not result in a PDF attachment; it will result in a base64-encoded PDF attachment tagged as a PDF, which will then be base64-encoded a second time by PHPMailer because it can't know what data you are providing. So decode the PDF data before attaching it:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment(base64_decode($base), 'pdfName.pdf');
```

Comment: firstly thanks for comment,  i already tried this but still return broken pdf file.

Comment: If you tried it, say so in your question. Now do as I suggested and *double check your data* to confirm exactly what data you do have. Instead of sending it by email, save it to a file and check it in there: if you have a corrupt PDF, emailing it isn't going to change anything, but it does add a new way for things to go wrong, so *check your data first*.